# When does the Wasserstein metric attain inequality WLOG?

Tags: probability, distance-functions, metric, measure-theory

I’m reading a classic paper [1] that describes a version of the Wasserstein metric (aka Mallows metric), defined as follows. Let $F$ and $G$ be probabilities in $\mathbb{R} ^B$, and let $U \sim F$ and $V \sim G$ be $B$-valued RVs with marginal distributions $F$ and $G$ and an arbitrary joint distribution. Then:

$$d_p(F,G) := \inf\limits_{ \substack{U \sim F \\ V \sim G} } E\Big[  || U-V||^p \Big]^{1/p}$$

The paper says the infimum is always attained for some joint distribution of $(U,V)$ and then goes on to prove various results by considering only the case in which the infimum is attained, "without loss of generality". For example (Lemma 8.6):

> In view of Lemma 8.1 [stating that the infimum is attained and that $d_2(.,.)$ is a metric], assume without loss of generality that $(U, V)$ are independent and $$d_p(F, G) = E\Big[  || U-V||^p \Big]^{1/p}$$

First, I don't understand why this holds WLOG. Second, I'm confused about why the infimum would be attained for *independent* $(U,V)$: intuitively, wouldn't opposite be true? I would expect the "distance" to be smallest when $(U,V)$ are as correlated as their marginals would allow.

### References

[1] Bickel, P. J., & Freedman, D. A. (1981). Some asymptotic theory for the bootstrap. The Annals of Statistics, 1196-1217.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, then note that apparently one of the authors is still alive https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/bickel/ contains contact info.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone, thanks. I'll try Bickel as a last resort, but let's see what the hive mind can do.

Comment: I know the paper spells it out, but when I was in school, I saw so much use and abuse of the WLOG "operator", that I developed a generalized WLOG operator, which stands for either without loss of generality or with loss of generality, as appropriate. At least the generalized WLOG operator is always valid.

Comment: Note that the setup for Lemma 8.6 is that you have $U_i, V_i$ independent across $i$, not that $U_i$ is independent of $V_i$.  Your quote seems slightly, but importantly, incorrect; the actual quote is "... assume without loss of generality that the pairs $(U_i, V_i)$ are independent".  Link: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176345637 ,  page 1213.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue basically has to do with how the proofs are structured; I think you've slightly misunderstood how the assumptions work with the proof itself.  Lemma 8.6 is just a proof that the triangle inequality holds for pairs of the form ($\sum U_i, \sum V_i)$ and the distance metric as defined at the top of Section 8: Mathematical Appendix:

[image]

where $B$ is a suitably-defined Banach space.

B&F start out by stating that in view of Lemma 8.1, they can assume that the infimum is attained (implicitly, for the function $E\{ ||\cdot||^p\}^{1/p}$ between $U_i$, $V_i$ and $\sum U_i$, $\sum V_i$), and there's no loss of generality in doing so, because 8.1 shows that the infimum *is* attained.  This fact is used in 8.1 in the proof that $d_p$ is a metric on $\Gamma_p$, i.e., part a is used to prove part b, so, by making that assumption, they can use the fact that $d_p$ is a metric in subsequent steps / lemmas.

ETA for the first point:

Note that the distance is actually between the laws $\alpha$ and $\beta$, not between specific random variables $X$ and $Y$.  The distance between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is defined as the infimum of the given function over *all* $X$ and $Y$ such that: a) $X$ and $Y$ are $B$-valued random variables where b) $X$ has law $\alpha$ and $Y$ has law $\beta$.  The point of the proof of Lemma 8.1 is that a pair of such r.v.s exist that attain the infimum, but the distance isn't between that pair, or any other pair for that matter, it's between the laws $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

With respect to your second question about why the infimum would be attained for independent ($U, V$) - I think you've slightly misunderstood the use of the independence argument.  The attainment of the infimum has nothing to do with orthogonality between $U_j, V_j$, as the proof of Lemma 8.1 makes no such assumption, and indeed nor does Lemma 8.6.  The orthogonality assumption is *across the pairs* $(U_j, V_j)$ ("let us assume without loss of generality that the pairs $(U_j, V_j)$ are independent") and is not used in the proof that the infimum is achieved (Lemma 8.1), but rather in the proof that the triangle inequality holds (Lemma 8.6).

ETA for the second point:

Now, when B&F write out 8.6, they refer to $(U_i, V_i)$ rather than $\alpha$ and $\beta$, which can certainly cause confusion.  But they do so because they are referring to the function $E\{ ||U-V||^p\}^{1/p}$, and doing so allows them to use Minkowski in their proof.  In general, that function is not equal to $d_p(\alpha, \beta)$, so the proof isn't helpful... but if we happen to choose the $U_i, V_i$ pair that achieve the infimum in Lemma 8.1, the function  *is* equal to $d_p(\alpha, \beta)$, by definition of the distance. Therefore, the proof using Minkowski can be transformed from a proof about $E\{ ||X-Y||^p\}^{1/p}$ to a proof about $d_p(\alpha, \beta)$, and the properties about $E\{ ||X-Y||^p\}^{1/p}$ which they just proved also hold for $d_p(\alpha, \beta)$, which is what we are really interested in.

Comment: (+1) I really appreciate your going back to the paper. This definitely clears up my misunderstanding of the independence issue. However, I'm still confused about the infimum attainment thing. It seems like they're actually using the equality itself in the proof, not just the properties of a metric. Wouldn't that imply that the proofs only hold for the specific random variables whose joint distribution attains the inf? For example, I'm looking at the last equality in the proof of Lemma 8.6:

Comment: $\sum E[ || U_j - V_j ||^p ]^{1/p} = \sum d_p(U_j,V_j)$, which would be $\ge$ for $(U_j, V_j)$ that don't attain the inf.

Comment: A similar equality happens in the proof of Lemma 8.9: $E[ (U-V)(U-V)'] = I_{n \times n} d^1_2(U_i, V_i)^2$, where $U,V$ are column vectors and $I_{n \times n}$ is the identity matrix. I would have expected $\ge$ for any non-equality-attaining general choice of $U,V$.

Comment: Added some edits, albeit a little hurriedly, to try to address your questions.

Comment: Oh!! Thank you! I think I finally understand. So when the arguments are RVs, as in $d_p(X,Y)$, instead of distribution functions, as in $d_p(F, G)$, they are NOT using those notations interchangeably, but rather referring to the *specific* $X,Y$ that attain the infimum. And then since $d_p(F, G)$ is defined only with reference to that very pair of $X,Y$ that attains the infimum, we can make the swap. Right?

Comment: Exactly so!  A little confusing, notationally, I admit.